# Will the nth Kissing Number always be the number of vertices of an uniform (or regular) n-polytope?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, dimension-theory-analysis, polytopes

For example, the 3rd Kissing Number, 12, is the number of vertices of an icosaedron; the 4th one, 24, is the number of vertices of a 16-cell truncation (and many others); the 8th one, 240, is the number of vertices of the $4_{21}$ 8-polytope (of the $E_8$ group), etc.

Is it possible to make a generalization of this phenomen or is it actually nothing but a coincidence?

Comment: If it were that easy, why would it have taken so long to establish $k(3) ≠ 13$ and $k(4) ≠ 25$?

Comment: @MJD I know, but that is not a reason for a phenoment not to exist

Comment: Regarding the regular polytope version of this question, and to expand on the comment of @MJD, the values of kissing numbers are unknown. But the regular polytopes are known. In dimension $n \ge 5$, there are only three of them: the simplex with $n+1$ vertices, the cube with $2^n$ vertices, and the "orthohedron" (generalizing the octahedron) with $2n$ vertices. If the $n^{\text{th}}$ kissing number were equal to one of those three numbers, we would know that --- meaning that someone (unfortunately not me) knows why it is not equal to any of these three numbers.

Answer (score 4):

To expand on my comment regarding the regular polytope version of this question, the answer is "no".

The kissing numbers are unknown, although crude bounds to them are known. From [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissing_number_problem) one may read that the kissing number in dimension $n=5$ is between $40$ and $44$.

The regular polytopes are known. In dimension $n \ge 5$, there are only three of them: the simplex with $n+1$ vertices, the cube with $2^n$ vertices, and the "orthohedron" (generalizing the octahedron) with $2n$ vertices. In dimension $n=5$, these three numbers are $5+1=6$, $2^5=32$, and $2 \cdot 5 = 10$. None of these three numbers are between $40$ and $44$.

One might wonder if something like this could "eventually" be true, i.e. be true for sufficiently large $n$. But the answer still appears to be "no", although I'm not sure whether this can yet be proved rigorously (as hinted in the comment of @MJD). Here's why.

On the wikipedia page cited above, you will see that the kissing numbers are believed to grow exponentially, which rules out $n+1$ and $2n$. You will also see from the table and the graph reproduced on that wikipedia page that although the base of the exponential is unknown, it appears to be strictly less than $2$, which rules out $2^n$.

Since there is as yet no proof of any of these asymptotic estimates (as far as I can tell in my quick and dirty reading of wikipedia), this all remains unknown in any rigorous sense.

Comment: Thank you! And what about Uniform Polytodes?

Comment: They seem more complicated than regular polytopes, but there is still easily available information on them. I suspect the answer will be similarly unknown, given the unknown status of the kissing number information.

Comment: @user3141592: Chiming in late on this one, but I will make the tangential observation that if one puts the kissing vectors at the corners of a hypercube inscribed within an $n$-dimensional unit hypersphere, *some* kissing unit hyperspheres will intersect whenever $(n-2)/n > 1/2$—that is, whenever $n > 4$.  In five dimensions, $32$ kissing unit hyperspheres arranged at the vertices of a hypercube will partially intersect, even though the kissing number for $n = 5$ is no less than $40$.